# WebSocket connection to 'wss://' failed: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: ssl, websocket, signalr

I'm getting 500 error when running SignalR on secure websocket when running on IIS Express.
Site is running on localhost:44300 with default cert.
It works just fine with `longPolling`.

When changing to `webSockets`, I'm getting following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 
'wss://localhost:44300/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken='
failed: Unexpected response code: 500
```

If the error is due to self-signed cert, how do I disable it with SignalR and websockets?

Or could it be caused by something else?

Comment: You need to check logs for more details on exception for error 500.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving this issue with initializing EventMachine, by inserting the following code in an initializer config/initializers/eventmachine.rb:

```
Thread.new { EventMachine.run } unless EventMachine.reactor_running? && EventMachine.reactor_thread.alive?
```

and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this out:

http://websocketstest.com/

BTW: Internal Error (500)